# how to apply odataqueryoptions against odata endpoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

CRM 2016 provides an odata endpoint such as:

```
https://mycrmorg.com/api/data/v8.1/
```

And it allows you to apply odata filters on it such as:

> https://mycrmorg.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts(8308AD1C-1B1A-E711-941B-00155DC0D345)

If I have a controller such as :

```
class AccountsController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
  {
    var endPoint = @"https://mycrmorg.com/api/data/v8.1/";
    //how do we apply the odata query options here??

  }   
}
```

**how do we apply the odata query options against this endpoint??**

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you simply want to get all the ODATA query options from your ODataQueryOptions object. You can get it from `RequestUri`:

```
class AccountsController
{
  public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
  {
    var stringOptions = options.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
    var endPoint = @"https://mycrmorg.com/api/data/v8.1";

    var endPointAndQuery = endPoint + stringOptions;
    //call Odata
  }   
}
```

`stringOptions` will contain for example something like this: `"/accounts?$filter=accountnumber eq '1234'"` which you can simply append to your endpoint and call other odata api.